# Process directory statistics recursively using Powershell

Tags: powershell, recursion, directory, filesize

I am currently using a script I wrote to use a Logparser query against a directory recursively to produce the following output:

```
QTY     TOT KB    AVRG KB MAXM KB MINM KB
------- --------- ------- ------- -------
3173881 175101609 55      85373   0
```

I would like to reproduce this using powershell in an attempt to make collecting this information more portable. (Not needing to install / copy logparser)

I searched and attempted to manipulate what examples I have found but can't quite get the structure down.

Here is the closest I have gotten:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Measure-Object -sum Length | Select-Object Count,Average,Sum
```

This returns:

```
Count Average                                                                     Sum
----- -------                                                                     ---
44663                                                                     40861708776
```

Any suggestions? I would prefer to stick to a "one line" command if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Measure-Object` only does what it's told, so if you only `-Sum`, you only get the Sum.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | Measure-Object -Sum -Average -Maximum -Minimum -Property Length | Select Count, Average, Sum, Maximum, Minimum
```

Answer (score 0):

Get-ChildItem is pretty slow; what about using RoboCopy to list the folder contents?

```
$Folder = "D:\Downloads"
robocopy $Folder $Folder /S /L /BYTES /NJH /NJS /NDL /V | 
    ForEach-Object { (-split $_)[1] } | 
    Measure-Object -Maximum -Minimum -Sum -Average | 
    Format-Table
```

Which goes to a one-liner:

```
robocopy $Folder $Folder /S /L /BYTES /NJH /NJS /NDL /V |%{(-split $_)[1]}|measure -a -s -ma -mi | ft
```

Robocopy options are:

```
/S - subdirectories (excluding empty ones)
/L - list files, don't do any copying or moving
/BYTES - show sizes in bytes, with no commas or anything
/NJH and /NJS - no header and summary lines in the output
/NDL - don't list directories
/V - verbose (do list individual files and their sizes)
```

Then the ForEach splits the output to drop the filename and robocopy status and just keep the size, and measure-object calculates the results, and format-table turns it into a nicer looking table output.